# Do the cathodes of all batteries increase in mass as the battery is used?

Tags: electrochemistry

I understand the mechanism behind the cathode's increasing mass in many batteries. As the cathode receives electrons, ions are reduced to form atoms. In short, more electrons equals more mass in the cathode. what I was wondering is whether or not there are batteries where the cathode does not increase in mass for whatever reason. Are there batteries where electrons, or some amount of mass is able to return to the anode? Thanks to anyone who responds to this question!

Comment: Electrodes of vanadium energy storage cell batteries have constant mass.VO2^+/VO^2+// V^3+/V^2+

Comment: Fuel cells? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fuel_cell

Answer (score 0):

The original zinc batteries have cathodes made of $\ce{MnO2}$ in contact of a solution containing $\ce{NH4Cl}$. When getting electrons from the zinc anode, the following reaction happens :$$\ce{2MnO2(s) + 2NH_4^+ + 2 e- -> Mn2O3(s)  +  H2O + 2 NH3}$$ The reaction produces $\ce{H2O + NH3}$ which both pass into solution. The cathode looses one oxygen atom when 2 electrons are coming. As $\ce{MnO2}$ molar weight is $\pu{87 g/mol}$, the cathode becomes lighter by about $\frac{16}{2·87} = 0.092 = 9.2$ %